# HTML class changes position when the window is resized

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to design a simple webpage where the design looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLLfS.jpg).

But I'm also trying to make the website fit on windows of almost any size, and when that happens the `.gameInfo` class jumps on top of the `.playerList` class when the window size is smaller than the width of those two combined, so the result ends up looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APHBk.png).

Obviously this looks very ugly and my goal is to try to make `.gameInfo` and `.playerList` as parallel as possible. My following code looks like this:

**index.html**:

```
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="gameState">
        </div>

        <div class="gameInfo">
        </div>

        <div class="playerList">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**style.css**

```
body{
    background-color: #FAF7F8;
    font-family: "Calibri",  sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container{
    width: 89%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.playerList{
    float: right;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #D4D4D4;
    width: 123px;
    height: 340px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: black;
}

.gameInfo{
    float: left;
    width: 89%;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #D4D4D4;
    height: 340px;
}

.gameState{
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    margin: 12px auto 12px auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #D4D4D4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're mixing fixed and percentage based widths, so I think this is a expected behaviour.

If `.gameInfo` has 89% of the page, then `.playerList` will get at most 11%. The problem is that `.playerList` has a fixed width (123px), so, when that's greater than the 11% of the page `.gameInfo` won't fit side by side with it.

**Edit:**
This it's a proper fluid-fixed layout:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="gameState"></div>
        <div class="playerList"></div>
        <div class="gameInfo"></div>
    </div>
</body>​

body{
    background-color: #FAF7F8;
    font-family: "Calibri",  sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container{
    width: 89%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.playerList{
    float: right;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #D4D4D4;
    width: 123px;
    height: 340px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: black;
}

.gameInfo{
    margin-right: 130px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #D4D4D4;
    height: 340px;
}

.gameState{
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    margin: 12px auto 12px auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #D4D4D4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: black;
}​
```

Comment: How would I resize .gameInfo according to the window width while still keeping the fixed width of .playerList?

Comment: I tried your solution and I now get this result when my window is at full width: [http://i.imgur.com/htCR6.png](http://i.imgur.com/htCR6.png)

Comment: Did you placed `<div class="playerList"></div>`before `<div class="gameInfo"></div>`? (look the HTML of my example)

Comment: Wow, now I feel like a bigger idiot than I did when asking this simple question. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may use @media queries for this problem if you want the page to be responsive.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

In that way, you may set or alter the size and position under a certain size of the browser. It's easy and its one of the trends today.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing two kinds of widths, pixels and percentages.
When you scale the browser window and thus the container div, the 11% you leave for your `.playerList` will be less than `123px` at some point.

The simplest solution I would say, is giving the `.gameInfo` a `margin-right:30px;` (a little bit more than the `.playerInfo` width due to borders and to leave a bit of space between.
You also have to remove the width and float attributes of the `.gameInfo`, so that it will appear next to the `.playerInfo` and take up all the horizontally available space(and you have to make the floating `.playerInfo` come first in html).

See your code with the mentioned changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/qyKny/7/

EDIT: Same solution as rdiazv just a minute ago, but I will leave this here for more extensive explanation and jsfiddle link.